# The axioms of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The author of my text proves the properties of a topological space—(T1-3)—by

---

[image]

---

But I don't really understand the statement in the proof of (T1) where he claims "...and, obviously, $X$ is open."

Is he saying that $X$ has to be open for that property to hold, or is he saying that he also proved that $X$ must be open. Because the former makes sense. Just making sure I'm thinking about it right.

Comment: To make "$X$ is open" obvious, you should begin by looking at the definition of "open". I don't see that definition in your picture, but presumably it occurs just a little earlier in the book. After you find the definition, apply it to the whole space $X$ and see what it says. Also, in connection with your comments on enedil's answer, note that it makes no sense to just say a set is open; you need to specify the space. For example, $[0,1]$ is not open in $\mathbb R$, but it is open in $[0,1]$.

Comment: My book doesn't use the word *in* to describe this behavior so I'm not sure what you mean. In the traditional sense, $[0,1]$ is closed, and $[0,1] = [0,1]$ which implies that if $[0,1]$ is in $[0,1]$ then it is also closed, no?

Comment: Also, the definition of *open set* in my book is just that every element of that set has an open ball contained within it, which $[0,1]$ doesn't.

Comment: $[0,1]$ is indeed closed in $[0,1]$, but that doesn't prevent it from being open in $[0,1]$. Indeed, any space is both open and closed in itself. Since your definition of "open set" uses the notion of "open ball", you should probably go back to the definition of "open ball" to see how it depends on the space in which you're working. For example, if your space is $[0,1]$, what is the open ball with center $0$ and radius $3$? How would it be different of the space were $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Please identify the book that you copied that image from.

Comment: *Introductory Functional Analysis*, by Kreyszig.

Answer (score 2):

**Notation.** Let $(M,\rho)$ be a metric space. Fix $x\in M$. Fix real number $r >0$. $$B(x,r)$$
is notation for $$\{\xi\in M:\rho(x,\xi)<r\}.$$

**Terminology.** Let $(M,\rho)$ be a metric space. Fix $S\subseteq M$. Say $S$ is *open* if for each $s\in S$, there exists $\delta=\delta(s)>0$, such that $B(s,\delta)\subseteq S$.

**Remark.** Let $(M,\rho)$ be a metric space. Then $M$ is open. Indeed, for each $\xi\in M$, define $\delta(\xi)=1$ (any positive real works). Then
$$B(\xi,\delta)\subseteq M.$$
As a result, $M$ is open. Notice: The ball only contains points in $M$. This is why $[0,1]$ is open when considering the metric space $([0,1],\rho)$, where $\rho(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Of course, $[0,1]$ is not open when considering the metric space $(\mathbb{R},\rho)$, where $\rho(x,y)=|x-y|$.

In short, being open is a relative terminology that depends on what space is being considered. This is why most mathematicians clarify that a set $S$ is open *in* $X$, where $S\subseteq X$ and $(X,\rho)$ is a metric space whose metric is understood via context; e.g. the metric induced by the established norm of a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think he means the latter -- in a metric space, a set $S$ is open, if for each its element, there is an open ball with positive radius centered at it, which is contained in $S$. Obviously, $X$ satisfies this definition, as every open ball is by definition a subset of $X$.

Comment: What if I take $X$ to be $[0,1]$? Then $\emptyset \in \mathscr{T}$ but $X \notin \mathscr{T}$

Comment: @Zduff what do you mean? Why it's not inside?

Comment: Because $\mathscr{T}$ is the collection of all open subsets of $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ is not an open subset of $[0,1]$, which means $[0,1]$ can't be an element of $\mathscr{T}$.

Comment: @Zduff it is open, why you claim otherwise? Note that in particular, no open ball in this topology contains number 1.5, since it's not a member of $[0, 1]$ (look once again at the definition of open ball)

Comment: Are you saying that $[0,1]$ is an open set?

Comment: I edited my comment, yes, it is open in $[0,1]$